# Emit the socket event only to specific tab in node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

`Greetings to all,

I am facing a complex situation (may be easy to you guys). I am using socket from react js and node js app. I have 2 parameters while create the socket instance and calling my first event. first is **socketID** and another is **QR unique id** which is something like room id. Currently I am using QR uinique id to join the room and emit the event. here is the code how I am emitting the event.

io.in(qr_unique_code).emit('paymentresponse',object}`

Now I need the following scenerio to be worked with ---

1. If I am hitting some api from frontend then need the event on the same browser/tab
2. If I refresh the same page (react app), then the event should not call at browser
3. If I do not refresh the page and open the new page on the new tab, then event must be different for both the tabs.

Actually the criteria is to buy some products through the socket, and the response event returns once the buy is successful. If user does not wait for the response and refreshes the page and buy for some other item, then the socket event would be called for the new product not for the existing product.

Thanks in advance

I tried this for the qr unique code and it working fine but not if I refresh the page.

io.in(qr_unique_code).emit('paymentresponse',object}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure i understand everything i've read there (i suggest you take the time to maybe edit & clarify your post a bit) but i think what you're looking for are basically callbacks ?

If so you're in luck, socket.IO does implement a callback feature since v3: https://socket.io/docs/v3/emitting-events/

Here is an exemple from their own site:

```
// server-side
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("update item", (arg1, arg2, callback) => {
    console.log(arg1); // 1
    console.log(arg2); // { name: "updated" }
    callback({
      status: "ok"
    });
  });
});

// client-side
socket.emit("update item", "1", { name: "updated" }, (response) => {
  console.log(response.status); // ok
});
```

This allows you to return your response only to the socket that made the original emit.

Comment: thanks for your response @N.K. Actually I am not looking for callback. I am looking for the something like in() or to() but with specific tab. If I refresh the page then socket should not be called with the old socket id. only new socket should be called. and also can we emit it with multiple parameters on to or in method?

Comment: @CodeGeek There is no easy way to do what you ask for. One would be to track the latest socket.io connection opened by your user, directly on the server, and then have logic to handle that problem on your server aswell, when you send back your response via io.emit.to(). Ie: i have a game, each time the user connects and access the chat, a sock.io tries to connect, during the handshake it sends the user's identification token, this token is verified on the server and then made a static property on the given sock, that way i know who owns it.

Comment: Also, yes, you can chain .to/in() calls. Look at the documentation.

Comment: There are no native, out of the box, ways for socket.io on your server to know which tabs you're in on your browser, that's just not possible. You'll have to write that logic yourself, maybe using what i proposed.